Google Formsのテストの回答で、点数を取得したい
Google Formsのテストの回答で、スプレッドシートに吐き出した結果を見ると問題数分の正解数となっています。例えば５問のうち１問正解なら 1/5 と書き出されます。
他のシートへ転記する際、シートのセルの値を取得して転記する際は 1 と入力してくれますが、e.values[] で取得すると 1/5 となってしまいます。
欲しいのは　問題数を含んだものでなく、この場合だと 1 だけが欲しい値ですが、どうしたらよいでしょうか？

正規表現で出来ました。
Score.replace(/\/.*[0-9]/g, "");

